# Parent is bigger than child image without paddings, borders and margins

Tags: html, css

Why parent height is bigger than child image? From where the extra pixels at the bottom come?

https://codepen.io/sevgin0954/pen/mdmxZzx

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.element {
  background-color: gray;
  border: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the gap left for descender text elements that hang below the line in most fonts (e.g. g, j, y). To remove it, change the `vertical-align`'s property from its default of `baseline` to `middle` or `top`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.element {
  background-color: gray;
  border: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100%;` on your `img` to make it stretch and take the rest of `element`'s space. The gray border at the bottom is the `element`'s extra space as it is longer than your actual image. Run the snippet if this fix your issue.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.element {
  background-color: gray;
  border: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706f00000003e62a57481e6aaeb533bea9b3">
  </div>
</div>
```